# Example of basically non-convergent Cauchy sequence

Tags: functional-analysis

We define convergent sequence as

$$u_n \rightarrow u \in U$$ if $\forall \epsilon >0 \ \exists N(\epsilon)$   so that
$$d(u_n,u)< \epsilon , \forall n > N$$
where
$$d(u_n,u) = ||u_n-u|| $$
We define a sequence to be Cauchy convergent sequence if
$\forall \epsilon >0 \ \exists N(\epsilon)$ so that
$$d(u_n,u_m)< \epsilon , \forall n,m > N$$
where
$$d(u_n,u_m) = ||u_n-u_m|| $$
It is easy to verify that convergence of a sequence $u_n$ implies Cauchy convergence, but the opposite is not necessary true.

How to provide an example of function sequence for this statement, that from Cauchy convergent sequence doesn't follow convergent sequence?

Answer (score 2):

Hint: use $[0,1]$ (where Cauchy sequences *do* converge), pick a convergent sequence, and then just remove its limit from the space.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of classic examples:

Take a sequence of rational numbers which converges to an irrational number. Such a sequence is convergent in $\mathbb{R}$ but not in $\mathbb{Q}$. For a fun example of this, consider the sequence given by $x_n = \frac{f_{n+1}}{f_n}$ for each natural number $n$ where $f_n$ is the n-th Fibonacci number. The rational sequence $(x_n)$ is Cauchy and converges in $\mathbb{R}$ to $\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$ but does not converge in $\mathbb{Q}$.

For an easier example, take the sequence $(1/n)$ in $(0,1)$. It is an easy exercise to see that this sequence is Cauchy but does not converge in $(0,1)$.